# Scope with Diction and null pointers

Tags: java, javafx, hashmap

I am having a problem displaying the information in a `HashMap` while in the start method of an FX program.

```
public class stack extends Application{

    String mCurrentLocation; // Store current location

    // Map to store name as keys and easting and northing as values
    HashMap<String, List <Double>> dict = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        stack mainObject = new stack();

        mainObject.run();// Method where the program is built

        launch(args);
    }
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        System.out.println("In in startFX: "); // debugging only
        System.out.println(dict);           // debugging only
        // More fx code
    }
    private void run(){

        System.out.println("In main");
        System.out.println(dict);

        //Read Northing and Easting input received from a txt file
        try{
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new 
            File("NorthingAndEastings.txt"));

            while(scanner.hasNext()){
                List<Double> coordinates = new ArrayList<>();
                String name = scanner.next(); // key
                Double easting = scanner.nextDouble();
                coordinates.add(easting); // list(0)
                Double northing = scanner.nextDouble();
                coordinates.add(northing); //list(1)
                this.dict.put(name, coordinates); 
            }
        scanner.close();
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("Sorry, could not open" 
            + "'NorthingAndEastings.txt' for reading. Stopping");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        // For debugging only
        for (Map.Entry me : dict.entrySet()){
            System.out.println("Name: "+me.getKey() + " Loc: " + 
                         me.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

In the `run()` method which gets called in main first, the `HashMap` which is a member variable gets populated from the text file. But when the code goes to FX where I would like to display the `HashMap` items the diction is empty. and I get `{};`

Comment: ` But when the code goes to FX` please post this code and how you are calling it ?

Comment: Not sure if the rest of the code in start() method is needed because with me using System.out.println(dict); in the start(), it is enough to show that while in start() dict is empty {}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method `launch` from `Application` class will launch a new instance of your stack class which will have an empty `dict`. If you want the lauched application to retain the values populated in `dict` than make `dict` a `static map` or populate your `dict` in start method.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Sanjeev thanks for the reply and help. So if you want to use variables in FX you would have to declare them in the start method or make them static? These are the only two ways?

Comment: @Taylor Yes these are the ways but i would always recommend start method over static declarations until unless static is must to have for example if all instaances needs same copy of data

Comment: Hi Sanjeev, ok I ended up having the dict being created and initialised in the start method. This works but not sure if this is an efficient way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think the issue might be caused by `stack mainObject = new stack();` - it is possible that you are creating a separate instance of `dict` to what you think you are using within `start`.

Comment: Hi Munyul, thanks for the help. I am interested in finding the correct way to do it. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @Taylor, if you changed your `dict` definition to static, that might solve your issue: `static HashMap<String, List <Double>> dict = new HashMap<>();`
Though, I'm not 100% sure of that...